# The president, the nickel and the dime

Tags: short-story, characters, naming

Not sure if this is on topic here:

I remember back when I was a kid, I read a story about a US president.

When he was a kid, he was stupid and fooled by people.
They often gave him a choice of a nickel and a dime. He didn't know, so he chose the bigger one which is the nickel. From then on, he became a joke for others.

They would give him the two coins and ask him to choose, and then walked away laughing.
One day a woman, being a good person, taught him that people were making fun of him and that the dime is smaller, but has more value than the nickel.

The kid (being a future president) said that he had known that a long time ago. However, if he had started picking the right coin, then people would have stopped giving him money.

I thought that is quite impressive, but I don't quite remember exactly the name of that president or if this anecdotal story is true. If it is, I hope someone can name him here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about anything to do with writing.

Comment: You could try [History.se], maybe?